# Query to return data only within the last year of a columns date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in a database table called EXPIRATION_DATE and need to filter my results to only bring in rows where the date in this column is within the last year.

The date format in the column is 18-JUN-21.
I imagine the filter need to be something like
WHERE EXPIRATION_DATE >= "logic to get todays date minus a year"
but I don't know what this logic is.
Thoughts?

Comment: A `DATE` is a binary data-type and does **NOT** have any stored format and it **ALWAYS** has year, month, day, hour, minute and second components. The user interface you are using may chose to display the binary data in a human readable format (i.e. `DD-MON-RR`) that hides the time components but they are always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `add_months` :

```
WHERE EXPIRATION_DATE >= add_months( trunc(sysdate), -12);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
where EXPIRATION_DATE >= sysdate - interval '1' year ;
```

Comment: This can have problems with leap years, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE EXPIRATION_DATE >= DATEADD(month, -12, GETDATE())
```

Or try the following:

```
WHERE EXPIRATION_DATE >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Although this is for T-SQL and I just noticed your tag is for ORACLE.  I'll leave this here though for anyone using SSMS etc.